# xslt to merge two web.xmls. The output should not have duplicate nodes

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am pretty much new to xslt. Need help in writing xslt that merges two web.xmls. The output should not have duplicate nodes.
Thanks in advance.

First web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>App Name</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>dojoUrl</param-name>
    <param-value>/dojo/src/1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js</param-value>
</context-param>
    <servlet>
 <servlet-name>HelloServlet1</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>HelloServlet.helloServlet1</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>HelloServlet2</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>HelloServlet.helloServlet2</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

---

Second web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>App Name</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>dojoUrl</param-name>
    <param-value>/dojo/1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js</param-value>
</context-param>
    <servlet>
 <servlet-name>HelloServlet1</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>HelloServlet.helloServlet1</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>HelloServlet3</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>HelloServlet.helloServlet3</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet3</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

---

Desired output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>App Name</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>dojoUrl</param-name>
    <param-value>/dojo/src/1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js</param-value>
</context-param>
    <servlet>
 <servlet-name>HelloServlet1</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>HelloServlet.helloServlet1</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>HelloServlet2</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>HelloServlet.helloServlet2</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>HelloServlet3</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>HelloServlet.helloServlet3</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet3</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

---

I am facing problem in getting information from second web.xml.

Here is the xslt I have written :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="fileName" select="'updates.xml'" />
    <xsl:param name="updates" select="document($fileName)" />

  <xsl:variable name="updateItems" select="$updates/web-app/servlet" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>`enter code here`

  <xsl:template match="web-app">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::servlet)] | servlet[not(servlet-name = $updateItems/servlet-name)]" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$updateItems" />
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Show us the code you have already tried. Explain to us what issues you are experiencing in your code and provide relative error outputs to further provide context to the problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

> I am facing problem in getting information from second web.xml.

The main problem with your XSLT is that the elements in both your XML documents are in a *namespace*. As a result, your `$updateItems` variable is empty and your second template does not match anything.

You need to declare the namespace in your XSLT, assign it a prefix and use that prefix when addressing elements in the given XML. Here's a corrected version of your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="fileName" select="'updates.xml'" />
<xsl:param name="updates" select="document($fileName)" />

<xsl:variable name="updateItems" select="$updates/ee:web-app/ee:servlet" />

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ee:web-app">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::ee:servlet)] | servlet[not(ee:servlet-name = $updateItems/ee:servlet-name)]" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$updateItems" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This still doesn't return the expected result, but that's for another question (where hopefully you will explain the exact merging criteria better than you did here).

Comment: Thnks for quick reply.Tried with the above xslt. But it is not giving expected output.

Comment: @Smit Read to the end.

Comment: yep. Michael can please help me in defining correct criteria to get the expected output

Comment: No. I don't know anything about your requirements, and your example is ambiguous. You need to explain exactly which nodes to take from which document.

Comment: My requirement is insert servlet node from second file to first file it if does not exists in first file.

Comment: My requirement is to write a xslt that merges two web.xmls. The resultant web.xml should not have duplicate servlet nodes.

Comment: Sorry, that 's not clear enough - and I don't have time for this game.

Answer (score 0):

It worked as exepcted after updating the XSLT as below :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:param name="fileName" select="'newweb.xml'" />
        <xsl:param name="updates" select="document($fileName)" />

        <xsl:variable name="updateItems" select="$updates/ee:web-app/ee:servlet" />

        <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="ee:web-app">
            <xsl:copy>
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::ee:servlet)] | ee:servlet[not(ee:servlet-name = $updateItems/ee:servlet-name)]" /> 
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="$updateItems" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Other than correcting the mistyped `servlet` to `ee:servlet`, what is the difference between your answer and mine?